# how to creatCustomize popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a customized popup window with treen radio buttons and one submit button, Once the User Selects any of the Radio Button, The Value has to be captured in the Parent Window

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried so far? Update your question to include these things!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the prompt() JavaScript method.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp

Comment: I tried with that somehow it is not working can you write the code and send it out to me